# RestClient and ENV troubles with Heroku

Tags: heroku, rake

I have an app on Heroku. Locally I am using Foreman and have a .ENV file for storing config vars. For this example let's say my API key is **123456789** and my Heroku app name is **acme**

**The following rake task works fine.**

```
task :scale_up => :environment do
  RestClient.post 'https://123456789@api.heroku.com/apps/acme/ps/scale', {:type => 'web', :qty => 3}
end
```

**To keep my keys private, I added the following to my .ENV file**

```
TASK_URL=https://123456789@api.heroku.com/apps/acme/ps/scale
```

**Now the following rake task doesn't work.**

```
task :scale_up => :environment do
  RestClient.post ENV['TASK_URL'], {:type => 'web', :qty => 3}
end
```

I have played around with the syntax arrangement and always up with one of the following:

- • syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
- • must pass :url
- • bad URI(is not URI?): http://ENV[TASK_URL]

**Help would be appreciated.**